# Revert to using CVC for payments autofill in Chrome, instead of user password?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome recently asked if I wanted to start using a new feature in which I could autofill my credit card information using my password instead of the card CVC.

I clicked 'yes' to give it a shot and found that it is poorly implemented and far slower than the CVC, with around a 5-second delay as opposed to the CVC which was instant.

However, I cannot find a way to go back or disable this setting. Is there a way?

Comment: Does it ask for the password or the PIN? Have you considered resetting Chrome?

Comment: OS user password. Please elaborate on resetting chrome.

Comment: See [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en). If you go this way, save bookmarks and note the extensions that you would like to re-install. Note that you can alternatively just create a new profile, keeping the old one, so you can always transfer missing data. See [Use Chrome with multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Answer (score 1):

By all accounts, getting rid of this option once it was activated
is pretty hard.

A very strong method of erasing all choices is to
[Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).
You may export and re-import bookmarks and other content, but in effect
you will end up with a clean installation of Chrome.

A softer method is to create a new profile, assuming that this option
is tied to the current profile. You may keep the old profile around
until you have transferred all the necessary data to the new one.
When no longer needed, the old profile may be deleted.

For more information see
[Use Chrome with multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Comment: Since the other answers were not valid solutions, I gave you the bounty. This may or may not work, I don't know, I just knew the others didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can disable the unwanted behavior you're seeing in Chrome's settings:

1. Type or paste the following URL into the Chrome address bar (links don't work for these internal pages).

   ```
   chrome://settings/payments
   ```

   This brings you to Settings > Autofill and passwords > Payment methods.
2. Turn off "Manually verify every time you pay using autofill".
   [image: Payment methods settings]

Comment: That's actually already off for me. Whatever this functionality is, it's probably somewhere under experiments or flags.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have activated using Windows Hello as an extra form of security ? You can find this under `chrome://password-manager/settings`. There you look for `"Use Windows Hello when filling passwords"` and turn that off.

Comment: This is on Mac actually.

Comment: Mac has a similar 'Use passkeys across your Apple devices' to use Apple's Keychain as password manager for Chrome.